# dojo FilteringSelect takes time to autocomplete, any hack to autocomplete it faster?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, dojo

Good Folks, I'm using dojo **FilteringSelect** to populate list of numbers on UI from database. I have observed that if I tab out immediately after keying in a valid value in the text box (valid = value is present in drop down list), text box turns red indicating that there's an error. If I enter a valid value, pause, then press tab, text box autocompletes.
So, I almost always end up having error in a filtering select while typing FAST. 
Is it a limitation of dojo or I can fix it somehow? I want filtering select to autocomplete even when I am typing 'heads-down'

see this link -- http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/FilteringSelect.html#keyboard

Official Dojo filtering select demo page also displays same behavior. Run any code from above link, type fast and tab out (eg. type Cal in the **filteringSelect** textbox of US states to match California)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a searchDelay of propretie's FilteringSelect, the default value is 200ms change it by best value for you.

best regards.
Hssain.

Comment: see this link without exemple but very explicite http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dojo/string#1_10dijit_form__SearchMixin_searchDelay

Comment: How do I override searchDelay?

Comment: var filteringSelect = new FilteringSelect({
        id: "stateSelect",
        name: "state",
        value: "CA",
        store: xxxx,
        searchAttr: "name"
    }, "stateSelect").startup();
});

Comment: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/FilteringSelect.html when you create instance of filteringSelect you have id, name, store, value then add searchDelay: 500 (that means 500ms)